# Regex to find consecutive new lines separated by spaces

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm using `str_replace("\n\n");` to find any two consecutive new lines `\n` but the problem is the text I'm working with isn't uniform. The new lines aren't aways back to back. They could be separated by any number of spaces or even a tab (found one). Don't like to use regex that much, but looks like I may need one here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$output = preg_replace('/\n\s*\n/s', '', $input);
```

Comment: Is the `\s*` basically the same as Andrew's `[ \t]*`?

Comment: @sami: `\s` means a "space" character, i.e. newline, literal space, or tab. The `*` means zero or more of them (and as many as possible). So, pretty much the same in this case, except that mine will match two *or more* consecutive newlines (and any spacing in-between) -- not sure if this is exactly what you want

Answer (score 1):

This should be a fairly simple regex if all you want to do is replace two line breaks with one.

```
preg_replace("/\n[ \t]*\n/is", "\n", $inputString);
```

The `[ \t]*` will match zero or more spaces or tabs between the line feeds.

Comment: Is `[ \t]*` basically the same as Cameron's `\s*`?